# How much information is required to manipulate a mechanism?

Tags: game-theory, mechanism-design

It is well-known that the first-price auction is *manipulable*, in that a player can improve his utility by bidding less than his true value. But successful manipulation requires information: the player should know the maximum bid of the other players. Otherwise, he might bid too low and lose the auction.

Other mechanisms require less information. For example, consider the *average mechanism* on a one-dimensional domain (each agent bids his ideal value, and the outcome is the average of all bids). Here, in order to bid successfully, a player only needs to know whether the average of the other players is higher or lower than his true value: if it is higher, he should bid the minimum value; if it is lower, he should bid the maximum value. So only a single bit of information is required, and one can say that this mechanism is easier to manipulate.

QUESTION: are there studies about the amount of information needed to manipulate various mechanisms?

Comment: In what sense does the average contain less information than the maximum?

Comment: The proposed manipulation of the average mechanism doesn't always work. If the average is very, very close to your optimum, the strategy might overcorrect and make things worse.

Comment: @HerrK. You do not need to know the exact average - only whether it is higher or lower than your value (one bit of information).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker you are right - this is not a very good example.